# How to set the font name and size in an excel pivot table using epplus

Tags: excel, pivot-table, font-size, epplus

How does one set the font size and font name in an excel pivot table using epplus? Setting the fonts for a range as shown below does not affect the overlying pivot table.

```
ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells[1, 1, 50, 50];
rng.Style.Font.Size = 8;
rng.Style.Font.Name = "Arial";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below one example to do that. Hope, this will be of help

---

```vb
Dim excelTemplate = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(strFullFileName))

Dim workSheetPivot As ExcelWorksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("WorksheetPivot")
Dim workSheetData As ExcelWorksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets("WorksheetData")

Dim dataRange = workSheetData.Cells(workSheetData.Dimension.Address)

Dim pivotTable = workSheetPivot.PivotTables.Add(workSheetPivot.Cells("B10"), dataRange, "PivotTable-1")
'Or
'Dim pivotTable = workSheetPivot.PivotTables.Add(workSheetPivot.Cells("B8"), workSheetData.Cells(1, 1, workSheetData.Dimension.End.Row, workSheetData.Dimension.End.Column), "PivotTable-1")


Dim styleWholeTable = pivotTable.Styles.AddWholeTable()
styleWholeTable.Style.Font.Name = "Arial"
styleWholeTable.Style.Font.Size = 8
            styleWholeTable.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben's solution works nicely. Translating the relevant VB to C#:

```
var wholetablestyle = pvt.Styles.AddWholeTable();
wholetablestyle.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
wholetablestyle.Style.Font.Size = 9;
```

where pvt is an EPPlus ExcelPivotTable